# Identifying edges in a connected component - Python

Tags: python-3.x, tree, networkx, connected-components

I have a set of connected components obtained from a tree `T`as follows.

[image]

To get all the connected components, I'm using the following code sample:

```
connectedcomponents = sorted(nx.connected_components(T), key = len,reverse=True)
```

This is what I'm getting;

```
[{66, 98, 68, 37, 7, 8, 73, 75, 44, 47, 81, 51, 19, 23, 55, 56, 58, 62, 63}, {97, 3, 6, 71, 39, 11, 77, 17, 60, 95}, {99, 5, 10, 43, 15, 20, 90, 92, 93}, {96, 4, 76, 80, 84, 53, 52}, {34, 74, 46, 18, 24, 61, 30}, {36, 9, 41, 83, 88, 57}, {65, 69, 40, 78, 21, 54}, {1, 2, 12, 13}, {89, 26, 70, 31}, {0, 42, 28, 79}, {32, 85, 86}, {59, 45, 94}, {82, 50, 22}, {64, 72}, {33, 14}, {16}, {87}, {48}, {91}, {49}, {67}, {29}, {35}, {25}, {38}, {27}]
```

I need to get the edges in each of these components. For an example, for the first component `{66, 98, 68, 37, 7, 8, 73, 75, 44, 47, 81, 51, 19, 23, 55, 56, 58, 62, 63}` I need a separate list of edges as `[(37,47),(47,7),(7,62),...]`.

I tried it as follows:

```
def nodes_connected(u, v):
if u in T.neighbors(v):
    return True
else:
    return False


for i in connectedcomponents:
    print(i)
    for u,v in i:
        nodes_connected("u", "v")
        edges.append((u,v))
```

But didn't work!!!

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Take a look at `connected_component_subgraphs` for a good starting point

Comment: @Joel, I tried it as `connectedcomponents = list(sorted(nx.connected_component_subgraphs(T), key = len, reverse=True))`. but I didn't get any output. Istead, it prints something like this; `[<networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x1a1cd3bd30>, <networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x1a259431d0>,... ]`

Comment: It did give output.  It's produced a list of graphs, each of which is one of the connected components.  Try `for G in connectedcomponents:
      print(G.order())`.  What do you have?  Can you figure out the rest?

Comment: @Joel, thanks,  I tried, but here's what I got; `22
16
15
6
6
4
3
3
2
2
2
2
2
2
2
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1` How can I identify the edges of each component? I need to iterate through edges and some special nodes in each component.

Comment: @Joel, Thanks, Joel, I got it!!! nicely done :)